# Why are boomers called boomers?

Tags: etymology

They didn't boom anything. Their parents did. Shouldn't they instead be called "the boomed"?

Comment: The population boomed with baby boomers.

Answer (score 4):

For the same reason teenagers are called teenagers and old-timers, old-timers.

[-ers denotes association with a group.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-er)

They're the product of the baby boom.

Comment: I don't get how teenager/old-timer is analogous to boomer.

Comment: It's an age group descriptor with the same suffix

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: just as teenagers doesn’t mean “people who teenage” and “old-timers” doesn’t mean “people who old-time”, “baby boomers” doesn’t mean “people who baby boom(ed)”. Your question seems to be based on that misanalysis of the suffix (“they didn’t boom anything”). “Boom” in “baby boom” is a noun, not a verb: “-er” can be attached to a noun X to form a new noun meaning “people associated with/from X”, not just “people who do X”.

Answer (score 3):

**boom**  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=boom)

> But it could just as well be from boom (n.2) on the notion of "sudden
>   burst." The verbal sense "burst into sudden activity" seems to be
>   slightly older (1871).

**baby boom**  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=boomer)

> coined 1941, from baby (n.) + boom (n.); derivative baby-boomer
>   (member of the one that began in the U.S. in 1945) is recorded by
>   1974.

and finally:

**boomer**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/261109?rskey=dexufW&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> boomer = baby boomer

Answer (score 1):

It's the babies that boomed, hence "baby boom."  When we say "economic boom," it's the economy that "booms," not the consumers and investors who contributed to the economic boom happening, its parents, if you will.  Anyway, baby boomers are the present-day adults of those booming babies.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boom?s=t
(see definition 3)

Comment: Correct. The babies were boomed, but it was the parents that boomed them. One that commences the act of booming is a boomer. One that is boomed is... well... boomed.

Comment: Incorrect.  I didn't say, "The babies *were* boomed"; I said, "It's the babies *that* boomed."  You're twisting my words, shifting my active voice sentence into the passive voice to make it seem like I was saying they weren't doing the booming when, in fact, I said they were and made no bones about it.  You need to take a moment, click on the link in my answer, and read definition three.

Comment: It’s actually the birth rate that booms, or increases. The baby boomers is a noun for those born during the time of the boom in the birth rate, usually considered to begin in 1946.